# How to sort the columns by length of values in an excel file in python ? (preferably using def)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a list of data as following. I need to add the current data to a new worksheet sorted by the length of the values in the third column (p_seq)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUF3W.jpg)

I was able to add the current data using openpyxl but I'm struggling with sorting them. Ideally I would like to create a function. Thank you in advance !

Comment: You should post your code so we can see how to help improve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    strings_col1 = ["abcdefgh", "ijklmn", "opqr", "stuvwxyz123"]
    sorted_list_col1 = list(sorted(strings_col1, key = len))
    print(sorted_list_col1)
```

output:

> ['opqr', 'ijklmn', 'abcdefgh', 'stuvwxyz123']

Comment: Please format code as code and explain how it helps the OP issue.